# how to turn off x ray in particle edit mode?

Tags: modeling, particles

I'm trying to Comb my subjects hair, but it seems as though as if a kind of x ray mode is turned on and I don't know how to turn it off.
[image: model in particle edit mode]

As you can see, the hair particles are going right through the bear and whenever I comb, it also counts the movement on the back of the bear's fur too.

Comment: There is no xray mode in particle edit mode (at least that I know of) Are there any unapplied modifiers in your stack that could cause that?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Just press the 'limit selection to visible' button. 
In particle or edit mode, 3d view bottom left, next to the propotional editing mode.

Comment: Please explain *where* this option can be found.

Comment: In particle or edit mode, 3d view bottom left, next to the propotional editing mode.

Comment: You need to edit that into your question. I was asking so when other people see your answer they understand, not for me.

Comment: Ok, now it 's clearer...